# Synchronize org mode between different machines

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am writing an org file that org babel will tangle into "custom.el"  as shown [here](https://github.com/sachac/.emacs.d/blob/83d21e473368adb1f63e582a6595450fcd0e787c/Sacha.org#org-agenda) and [here](https://github.com/danielmai/.emacs.d).

My problem is that on one machine the path to my agenda files is `C:/Users/Username/Dropbox/file.org`  while on anther machine it is `C:/Users/DifferentUserName/Dropbox/file.org`.

I can setq the org-directory to the the correct path on different machines with:

```
(setq org-directory 
  (car  ;; with car returned value is type 'string' witout car returned type is 'cons'  
      (delq nil
         (mapcar (lambda(x) (and (file-directory-p x) x))
                       '("c:/Users/marka/Dropbox/Apps/OrgMode"
                         "c:/Users/Mark/Dropbox/Apps/OrgMode"
                         "c:/Users/msmith/Dropbox/Apps/OrgMode")))))
```

With a single agenda file, using concat `(concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")` returns the desired path to the agenda file `"c:/Users/Mark/Dropbox/Apps/OrgMode/gtd_work.org"`.

Unfortunately multiple uses of  the `concat` function when nested in the `setq`  appears to stop functioning:

```
>  (setq org-agenda-files                             
>             '((concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")
>               (concat org-directory "/gtd_proging.org")
>               (concat org-directory "/gtd_home.org")
>               (concat org-directory "/DailyRoutine.org")))
```

Using `C-h v` to find the value of `org-agenda-files` yields:

```
org-agenda-files is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is ((concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")
 (concat org-directory "/gtd_proging.org")
 (concat org-directory "/gtd_home.org")
 (concat org-directory "/DailyRoutine.org"))
```

Additionally I have tried:

1. Removing the single quote in the `setq`, this raises an `Invalid function: (concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")` exception.
2. `mapcar` and `mapc` raise `Wrong type argument: stringp, (concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")` exceptions.
3. Using `~/file.org` without concat returns nil

I am doing this in scratch right now as config.org is w.i.p.  Will org concat the path to the agenda files? Am I not using concat correctly?  If I write out the full path for each file on each computer and use `(mapcar (lambda (x) (and (file-exists-p x) x))` it will correctly select the machine specific path, however, this results in the first world problem of having to specify 20~40 paths rather than 8~12.

Solution by amitp below works for both the `setq` and for the:

```
(setq org-agenda-files
      (delq nil
            (mapcar (lambda (x) (and (file-exists-p x) x))
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: How about programmatically distinguishing between machines and just live with different paths?  For example, evaluate `(x-server-version)` and/or use other methods to distinguish the OS, etc. -- e.g., `system-type`; `feature-p 'ns`, etc.  That way, the paths will be programmatically adjusted depending upon which computer you are using.  To synchronize, I use `rsync` instead of Dropbox and I do it manually as needed.  I sync my whole installation to desktops and laptops, and to an iPhone (backup) and up to a shared web server (backup).

Comment: Please place a check-mark next to the correct answer; and, if you are happy with either of the answers, then click the up-arrow button to give them a an extra brownie-point.  In addition to @amitp answer below, you can also use a back-tick instead of a single-quote and place a comma before anything in the list that needs to be evaluated.  I can't do a back-tick in a comment because of the formatting that stackexchange uses, so I can't do a demonstration of the back-tick -- here is a comma demonstration though:  `,(concat ....)`  Perhaps @amitp could update the answer with another example.

Comment: Tick done, I did try and up vote earlier but as I have only been "writing" elisp for 2 days now I have not been around enough to collect the required 15 reputation.  I appreciate the guidance on protocol as well.

Comment: Backticks are a little tricky but yes, ``… `(,(concat …) ,(concat …)) `` will be the same as `(list (concat …) (concat …))` in this case. Backtick/comma is useful when you want to partially quote something, but some piece of it you want to evaluate without the quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single quote (`'`) tells lisp not to evaluate(run) the thing, but to leave it as is. When you write `'((concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org") …)` it tells it *not* to actually run the concat function, but instead leave the word "concat" in there. When you removed the `'` it didn't work either because it didn't know that you wanted all those things put into a list. The good news is that it's easy to make them into a list: the function name is `list` so you replace `'(…)` with `(list …)`.

Try changing

```
(setq org-agenda-files
         '((concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")
           (concat org-directory "/gtd_proging.org")
           (concat org-directory "/gtd_home.org")
           (concat org-directory "/DailyRoutine.org")))
```

to

```
(setq org-agenda-files
         (list
           (concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org")
           (concat org-directory "/gtd_proging.org")
           (concat org-directory "/gtd_home.org")
           (concat org-directory "/DailyRoutine.org")))
```

Comment: Another way to do this is with the shorthand of ` (backtick, usually found above the tab key) instead of a single quote, and prefix a comma before any child list that should be evaluated. This is useful if the concats are buried in a larger list, I do it when setting up my org capture templates. e.g.:
 `(,(concat org-directory "/gtd_work.org") ,(concat org-directory "/gtd-proging.org") ...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using just the string value, perhaps use `expand-file-name`? I believe this expands to the correct cross platform value on windows.

You could define a user constant to make it easy to use in multiple places, just like [this bit from spacemacs core](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/core/core-load-paths.el#L45):

```
(defconst user-home-directory
  (expand-file-name "~/")
  "User home directory (~/).")
```